# PowerShell I want to cut off a string after a specific character sequence

Tags: string, powershell, parsing, split

I am trying to parse a string variable where everything after -354 gets cut off.

I have variables that look like this: NameOfFile-354-XX.pdf

Where NameOfFile can be any length and -XX can be anything or not even there at all.

I want the print of this variable to be: NameOfFile-354

How do I cut the variable so it cuts after -354?

What I have tried so far:

```
$FileArray = @("Name1-354-03.pdf", "Name23-354-H11.pdf", "Name354-354-02.pdf", "Name3545-354.pdf")
ForEach ($n in $FileArray){
     Write-Host $n.Substring(0, $n.lastIndexOf('-354'))
}
```

I want the output to be this:

```
Name1-354
Name23-354
Name354-354
Name3545-354
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @DonCummins Is the `-354` part always that exact sequence of characters? Or might it be a different number for example, eg. `Name123-987-ABC.pdf -> Name123-987`?

Comment: It will always be -354, everything else is susceptible to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `-354` is a constant value:

```
$FileArray = [System.IO.FileInfo[]]@(
    "Name1-354-03.pdf", "Name23-354-H11.pdf", "Name354-354-02.pdf", "Name3545-354.pdf"
)
$FileArray.ForEach({ $_.Name -replace '(?<=-354).*(\.pdf)', '$1' })

# Outputs:
Name1-354.pdf
Name23-354.pdf
Name354-354.pdf
Name3545-354.pdf
```

For *regex* explanation: https://regex101.com/r/4Butm2/1

Comment: This worked perfectly after a slight edit to the regex: (?<=-354).*()

Answer (score 1):

I am not a regex pro but would something like this work for you?

```
$string = "NameOfFile-354-XX.pdf"
$regex = "(.*)(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+(.)(.*))"
$match = $string -replace $regex,'$1'
```

Output would be like this:

```
PS C:\temp> $string = "NameOfFile-354-XX.pdf"
$regex = "(.*)(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+(.)(.*))"
$match = $string -replace $regex,'$1'

Write-Host $match
NameOfFile-354

PS C:\temp>
```

Regex details: https://regex101.com/r/Fw8F3i/1

Comment: This works for everything except: Name3545-354.pdf 
What edits can I make to make it work for that?

Answer (score 1):

A *regex* solution - such as in [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70854536/45375) - is definitely an option, but the only thing missing from your original attempt is to *add the length of the substring you're searching for* - i.e. `'-354'.Length` == `4` - to the 2nd `.Substring()` argument, so as to include that substring in the string returned:

```
"Name1-354-03.pdf", "Name23-354-H11.pdf", "Name354-354-02.pdf", "Name3545-354.pdf" | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $_.Substring(0, $_.LastIndexOf('-354') + 4) # Note the + 4
  }
```